# Infinite sheet in static magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

What happens if I add a infinite sheet of a perfect conductor in a constant applied magnetic field perpendicular to the surface? e.g. I have a sheet in the x-y plane and I apply $B_0 \hat{\mathbf{z}}$. What will the scalar potential become apart from the $-B_0 z$ term?